# Call to undefined method Product_model::product()

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

```
public function save_edit() {

    parent::__save_edit();
    $this->db = $this->load->database('default', true);
    $this->load->model('product_model','',TRUE);
    $id = $this->input->post('item_id');

    $array_item = array(
        'item_name' => $this->input->post('item_name'),
        'note' => $this->input->post('item_note'),
        'stock' => $this->input->post('item_stock'),
        'price' => $this->input->post('item_price'),
        'unit' => $this->input->post('item_unit')
        );

    $this->load->model('product_model');
    $this->product_model->update($id,$array_item);
    redirect('index.php/product');
}

public function edit(){
        $this->db = $this->load->database('default', true);
        $this->load->model('product_model');
        **$data['product'] = $this->product_model->product($this->uri->segment(3))->row_array();**
        $this->load->view('index.php/product_edit',$data);
}
```

error at line

```
$data['product'] = $this->product_model->product($this->uri->segment(3))->row_array();
```

Comment: You post is mostly code, please try to add some details.

Comment: Show product model code. Edit, and remove version tag that is not related to your application.

Comment: It doesn't take a genius to figure out what the error is telling you. The product model either has a product method or it doesn't, and this error says that it doesn't. What are you hoping for?

Comment: I am not sure what this  `parent::__save_edit();`
 is for but this is codeigniter way http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors

Comment: Also re edit your question with the model as well.

Comment: this question is unclear, please explain in detail.

Comment: please check my answer. let me know any help

Answer (score 0):

your get this error because. your model i.e "**product_model**" does not contain any product function. 
Hence you get "Call to undefined method Product_model::product()" error